# cant get ifstream to work in XCode

Tags: c++, xcode, ifstream

No matter what I try, I cant get the following code to work correctly.

```
ifstream inFile;
inFile.open("sampleplanet");
cout << (inFile.good()); //prints a 1
int levelLW = 0;
int numLevels = 0;
inFile >> levelLW >> numLevels;
cout << (inFile.good()); //prints a 0
```

at the first cout << (inFile.good());, it prints a 1 and at the second a 0. Which tells me that the file is opening correctly, but inFile is failing as soon as read in from it. The file has more then enough lines/characters, so there is no way I have tried to read past the end of the file by that point.

File contents:

```
8
2
#level 2
XXXXXXXX
X......X
X..X..XX
X.X....X
X..XX..X
XXXX...X
X...T..X
XXX..XXX
#level 1
XXXXXXXX
X......X
X..X.XXX
X.X..X.X
X..XX..X
X......X
X^....SX
XXX.^XXX
```

Comment: What is the contents of the file and what are the values of levelLW and numLevels at the end of this block?  My guess is that inFile >> levelLW >> numLevels; is greedily consuming more bytes than you anticipate.

Comment: they both still have the value of 0 after the inFile >>

Comment: My guess is that the input file has some invisible characters. On unix, I will run `hexdump -b <file>` to view the contents of the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out to be an issue with X-Code. I created a project in net beans using the same exact code and had no problems. Weird.

Update:
In my X-Code project, I changed my active SDK from Mac OS 10.6 to Mac OS 10.5 and everything works fine now.

Comment: It's a known bug. See my answer for a link.

Answer (score 3):

It's a known bug. From Xcode 3.2.1's [Release Notes](http://tuvix.apple.com/mac/library/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001051-DontLinkElementID_1):

> The default gcc 4.2 compiler is not
>   compatible with the Standard C++
>   Library Debug Mode. C++ programs
>   compiled with Xcode 3.2 may not work
>   in the Debug configuration. To fix
>   this, set the Compiler Version to 4.0,
>   or edit the Debug configuration’s
>   Preprocessor Macros and remove the
>   entries:
>   `_GLIBCXX_DEBUG=1
>   _GLIBCXX_DEBUG_PEDANTIC=1`

Answer (score 1):

I reproduced and tested your code and file and my output was 11 and both levelLW and numLevels were set as expected.  I would definitely take a hard look at hidden characters in your file (or lack thereof).  I like to use Notepad++ with "Show all characters" enabled.  My file is exactly what you posted with a carriage return and a linefeed at the end of each line.

Comment: I just retyped the entire file using carrige returns and line feeds at the end, and am still having no luck

Comment: Do you #include <iostream>, then #include <fstream>?  Note easier way to open file is: ifstream inFile ("sampleplanet");.  And easier way to test file is: if (inFile) { inFile >> levelLW >> numLevels; }.

Answer (score 1):

You said the first inFile.good() prints out 1.  That should mean the file opened OK.  Because you said "it works through the terminal but not XCode" in tehMick post - for what it's worth - when I tested this, I ran into the following problem: my IDE (C++Builder) runs the program out of a DEBUG directory (when you are in debug mode).  I needed to place "sampleplanet" in the DEBUG directory or use a path in the open that found the file like "..\\sampleplanet".

```
+MyProjectDirectory
|  mymain.cpp (Even though this is where I had the source file..)
|  sampleplanet
+--DebugDirectory
     mymain.obj
     mymain.exe (the program runs out of this directory.)
```

Once I took care of the above issue everything worked as expected using the above code and file.  I checked the file in Notepadd++ to confirm the [CR][LF] after every line.  If you create the file in Linux, it may have only [LF] however (I did everything under Windows).