# ifstream does not work in Xcode?

Tags: c++, ifstream

I am attempting to work with some files using an ifstream. Everything appears to be fine, but when I attempt to open a file it will not work. Whether I attempt it as inputting a string variable or a string literal for the name. The files that I am attempting to access are in the same directory as the project and do contain contents.

The project does not display any errors and will compile, but it will just say that it can't access the file every time.

The additional headers, "simpio.h" and "console.h" are just libraries provided by stanford.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "console.h"
#include "simpio.h"
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int countLines(ifstream & in)
{
    int count = 0;
    while (true) {
        string line;
        getline(in, line);
        if (in.fail()) break;
        count++;
    }
    return count;
}

int main()
{
    ifstream in;
    while (true) {
        cout << "Enter name: ";
        string s = getLine();
        in.open(s.c_str());
        if (!in.fail()) break;
        cout << "Couldn't open file, try again!" << endl;
        in.clear();
    }



    cout << "Num lines = " << countLines(in) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Any help would be great! Thanks!

Comment: Are you starting the program in the same directory as the file you're looking for?

Comment: What do you mean by that? The program and all of the files are within the same project folder.

Comment: `ifstream` surely doesn't work "in Xcode". It works in the standard library, in your program, etc. The features a class provides depend solely on the class, not on the IDE, the weather or the current mood of your neighbor's cat...

Comment: what is `getLine()`? I see you're using `getline(in, line)` in your countLines method. Are you sure it's working? You should print out `s` to see if it's reading properly.

Comment: getLine() is a function provided by those extra headers that I use. I did just test it again and it prints out correctly.

Comment: this has already been asked [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2107122/cant-get-ifstream-to-work-in-xcode)

Comment: I did read that, but it did not seem to help anything. I am on Xcode 4.6 so it's a bit different.

Comment: @H2CO3 This is actually a bug in Xcode, if you run the same code in another IDE it will work.

Comment: I suspect that the current directory isn't what you think it is.  Try printing out the cwd using `getcwd(cwd, sizeof(cwd));` to verify it.

Comment: @JonathanD That's impossible, unless the IDE itself provides the implementation of the `ifstream` class (which it doesn't).

Comment: @H2CO3 OH ok, i will check again

Comment: @JonathanD No problem, just saying.

Comment: @MichaelBurr How do I go about testing with the getcwd() function? I apologize I am relatively new.

Comment: @H2CO3 You are probably right but i still think the title should be "ifstream does not work in xcode?" because this problem is only occuring in xcode.

Comment: @MichaelBurr try to use this path: "/Developer/afile.txt" and check if the file in the developer folder has been created.

Comment: @Jonathan: See here for an example to print the current directory: http://stackoverflow.com/a/298518/12711

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two options:

1) Use Objective-C++ ( remove the .m extension and replace it with .mm)

2) Go to the project settings and add those values:

```
GLIBCXX_DEBUG=1 
GLIBCXXDEBUGPEDANTIC=1
```

in the preprocessor macros.

Older Xcode:
[image]
!
Newer Xcode:

[image]!

Example code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    ofstream myfile;
    myfile.open ("/Developer/afile.txt");
        if(!myfile)
        {
        std::cout << "ERROR" std::endl;
        }    
    myfile << "Writing this to a file.\n";
    myfile.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I went to that area and the field was already blank. So I didn't even have something to delete. Any ideas?

Comment: Yes sorry i typed it wrong, you have to add them ( where it says multiple values or something liek that)

Comment: I cannot access that macro field to edit/insert the text you have provided. Anything special that I need to do in order for it to work?

Comment: Why can't you acess it? just double click and click on the + in the bottom left corner to add a value

Comment: Nothing happens when I double click it. No field appears for me to type or add. The only thing I can do is arrow down, which then displays "debug".

Comment: You have to double ckick a bit on the right of it, at the place you want to add the values

Comment: Well that makes me feel like an idiot.. But I got the values inserted and the same problem arrises even after that. The file is still not being found. Is there anything special that I have to do with the file aside from having it in the project folder?

Comment: are you sure you added two seperate values? I will add an example code.

Comment: That did successfully open the file. So how do I go about putting my file into the correct directory for use? I am attempting to open and read in comparison to writing, too.

Comment: Just change the directory, now that ifstream works use this [reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ifstream/) if you have more questions

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to mess with anything in Xcode, fearing that you might break some other setting, do this:

As soon as you build and run your console program or app, go to the file list usually on the left side where the project is laid out, find the "Projects" directory, right click or option-click and select "Show in Finder". This is where Xcode dumps your builds every time you run it for that particular project. Every workspace will have its own build folder. You should find the file you selected or created there, if you want to add your own file there just drag it and you can then call it from your console or app program: myfile.open("file.txt");

Or just change the Working Directory for the project and use that folder which is probably a lot more accessible than /Developer/Gibberish/Build/Debug/whatever.

This makes it easy to port your code over to Win32 or other systems, at least for me it has.

Answer (score 0):

http://kentarotanaka.com/how-to-read-input-file-for-c-in-xcode/

Moving the text file to the projects directory of the workspace would help as mentioned in the above link.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.